# Continue Transition from where Animation Ended

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations, css-transforms

See the following button animation:

```css
html {
  background: white;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 10px 24px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-property: color, background, border-color;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.button:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.button:hover ._background:after {
  transform: translateX(0);
  animation: fill-horizontal 0.3s linear 0s 1;
}
.button ._background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.button ._background:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #000;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: transform .3s;
}

@keyframes fill-horizontal {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<a class="button" href="javascript:">
  <div class="_background"></div>
  Button
</a>
```

The intended animation is to sweep the `._background:after` element in from the left, and then out to the right like so:

1. `translateX(-100%)`
2. `translateX(0)` - Hover
3. `translateX(100%)` - Remove Hover

Whilst the animation works as intended when the user hovers for the duration of the CSS animation (`.3s`), it looks terrible if the user 'unhovers' before the CSS animation completes.

I would like the `transition` to `translateX(100%)` to continue from where the `animation` finished. Is this even possible?

**NOTE** - I am aware that the `div._background` element is not necessary, this has additional functionality that is not relevant to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider the same effect differently in order to avoid this bad effect:

Here is an idea using background animation where the trick is to change the position only after the size has changed.

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 10px 24px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-image:linear-gradient(#000,#000);
  background-size:0% 100%;
  background-position:left;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-origin:border-box;
  transition:color 0.3s, background-size 0.3s, background-position 0s 0.3s;
}
.button:hover {
  color:#fff;
  background-size:100% 100%;
  background-position:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">Some text</div>
```

Using this method, you will have a transition back in case you unhover rapidly.

---

A hacky idea to force the animation to complete is to consider a pseudo element that will make the hover area bigger and be sure you will keep the hover until the end:

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 10px 24px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-image:linear-gradient(#000,#000);
  background-size:0% 100%;
  background-position:left;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-origin:border-box;
  transition:color 0.3s, background-size 0.3s, background-position 0s 0.3s;
}
.button:hover {
  color:#fff;
  background-size:100% 100%;
  background-position:right;
}

.button:hover:before {
  content:"";
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:99;
  animation:remove 0s 0.3s forwards;
}
@keyframes remove {
  to {
    top:100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="button">Some text</div>
```